# JQuery Wordpress gallery

Tags: jquery, plugin-recommendation, gallery

I would like to know if it's possible to create a gallery like that one using WordPress: http://jfdelsalle.com/naaman.swf

Is there any plugin close to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's possible. [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/themes/classic/) is a jQuery plugin that is similar, but better (fancy slide transition effects and more).

You could include it yourself (see their documentation) or if you prefer WordPress plugins look at [Photo Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/photo-galleria/) which seems like it's based on galleria (haven't tried it).

Another really popular gallery plugin is the [NEXTGen Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/). I'm not sure if it supports the slideshow functionality seen in your link out of the box, though. I guess some coding is required for that.